# Core data - Unacceptable type of value for attribute

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, swift, core-data

I'm trying to save to my core data, like I've done a thousand times before, and suddenly this error pops up saying

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for
>   attribute: property = "messageType"; desired type = NSNumber; given
>   type = DemoApp.SendMessageViewController; value =
>   DemoApp.SendMessageViewController.'

And it makes no sense at all, because properties are defined as `double` and I'm definitely giving it an NSNumber. My code looks like this:

```
        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Message", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)

        var newMessage = Message(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)

        newMessage.receiver = receiver
        newMessage.sender = PFUser.currentUser().username
        newMessage.readByReceiver = false
        newMessage.readBySender = false
        newMessage.dateSent = NSDate()

        if memberMessage{
            newMessage.messType = 2
        }else{
            newMessage.messType = 0
        }

        contxt.save(nil)
```

Any suggestions to why this happens would be appreciated, as I already said, I've used this code before, and it should work.

EDIT: My Message-class

```
@objc(Message)
class Message: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var dateSent: NSDate
    @NSManaged var messType: Double
    @NSManaged var revealingMessage: Bool
    @NSManaged var receiver: String
    @NSManaged var sender: String
    @NSManaged var readByReceiver: Bool
    @NSManaged var readBySender: Bool
}
```

Comment: Please show us your Message class.

Comment: @c0dev it has now been added

Comment: Is that code the recent? Because messType is called 'messageType' in your error message. Make sure to name it the same way as in your CoreDataModel.

Comment: @c0dev Oh yes, I tried to delete and re-add the property with another name, and that was all I changed, everything else is the same.

Comment: @c0dev and yes, it has the same name.

Comment: Did it work before with the same setup.(The same app)?

Comment: @c0dev No not the same app, but another app and with the exact same setup. I'm starting to think this is a bug, because I've tried moving the code around (copy and paste) between the other lines where I set the properties, and the error changes to for example "given type = reavealingMessage". I've tried coming up with a pattern, but there seems to be none, I'll just try to rebuild the core data-model and write the code over again.

Comment: Just clean your project and remove it from the iOS simulator before you redo everything. That often was helpful, because sometimes it's a bit buggy.

Comment: I had the same problem and found it was missing a class on the entity. See here for the fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383592/swift-unacceptable-type-of-value-for-attribute-when-creating-new-nsentity